# In a Laravel app, how can I alter a users password directly in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm migrating a Laravel app from one host to another.

I've moved the app to a local environment for testing.
In order to test it, I need to log in.

I have usernames but not passwords.

I have no idea what artisan/tinker are, and afaict they are not bundled with the app.

I have control over the environment, including direct access to the database, which is mysql.

How can I change a users password directly in the database?

Comment: You have to store the passwords encrypted, so you must use a process in the middle like PHP (Laravel)

Comment: Simple make one method and covert password to hash and used it directly

Answer (score 1):

Create a page name it anything and write this code inside it:

```
$password = 'hello';
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo $hashed_password;
```

Then run the file and copy this hashed password and insert it in some table row. You can log in with a "hello" password